# How should I inject behaviour into an Entity

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I am exploring the use of Entity Framework Database First and I am trying to understand if I should inject behavior into an entity, and if so, what is the best technique for doing this.  I typically have done this in the past to avoid anemic domain objects.  A couple use cases are where I inject a specification into an entity (specification pattern/define composable business rules) or where I perhaps inject a ninject implemented factory into a root entity where the binding of the implementation is determined by a strategy/factory method at point of use) So for example below, I would use an IOC to inject in ISomethingSpec implementation.

```
 class Foo
 {
    void DoSomething()
    { 
        if(somethingSpec.SatisfiedBy(this)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

May I ask, Should I consider a different pattern for associating behavior with an entity?  Or if it is reasonable, is using partial classes/property and method injection the best option where I am using EF5 with database first?

This is my first post, so I hope it's format is not too far off the mark. I posted as I have looked at other questions that are similar but I could not determine a consensus on best practice for associating behavior with Domain objects /EF Entities.

Answer (score 4):

I use the [specification pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern) with Entity Framework to filter the data that is retrieved from the database. I think you can use the same approach and adapt it to your needs.

You can use a DI container to inject your specifications and other objects you may need. First step is to define a contract for your specification objects, something like this:

```
public interface ISpecification<T> where T : class
{
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetExpression();
    bool IsSatisfiedBy(T entity);
}
```

A generic Specification object can be defined like this:

```
public class Specification<T> : ISpecification<T> where T : class
{
    private Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression;

    public Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetExpression()
    {
        return expression;
    }

    public Specification(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
    {
        this.expression = expression;
    }

    public bool IsSatisfiedBy(T entity)
    {
        var query = (new[] { entity }).AsQueryable();

        return query.Any(this.expression);
    }
}
```

And then you can change your Foo class like this, so you can inject the dependency using a DI/IoC container:

```
public class Foo()
{
    public ISpecification<Foo> Specification 
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public Foo(ISpecification<Foo> specification)
    {
        this.Specification = specification;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    { 
        if(Specification.SatisfiedBy(this))
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Creating and using a specification:

```
// example - create one specification
Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> expression =  ....;  
ISpecification<Foo> fooSpecification = new Specification<Foo>(expression);


// using the specification with linq
var entities = dbContext.Foos.Where(fooSpecification.GetExpression());


// performing validation
var foo = new Foo{
    // ....
};

if(fooSpecification.IsSatisfiedBy(foo))
{
    // do something....
}
```

More details here:

http://ruijarimba.wordpress.com/2011/06/05/entity-framework-and-t4-generate-specification-objects-for-your-entities/

Comment: This is interesting! Can you include a linq query with a specification in it that demonstrates that the specification gets translated into SQL?

Comment: @GertArnold: included examples in my answer

Comment: Hi, thats exactly the pattern I use (Specification<T> etc)  I will have a read of that link, thanks.

Comment: @Rui Jarimba Ive downloaded your code and it looks like a more advanced versionm of the spec pattern im using, so good learn for me there. Next step is to inject the specs into the repositories and entitites such that specifications associated with the querying of the model are injected into the repository, and specifications associated with a domain entity are injected into the entity.  So for the latter it would be like my example foo above.  Should I use T4 for this or perhaps partial classes? The reason for this is to avoid SRP Violations (hooking up specs to target objects)

Comment: @jonathandudgeon: you can ignore the T4 part of the blog article, the imprtant thing here is how to create and use the specifications. You're not violating the SRP because the specification is independent from the domain object, and you can pass any specification to your domain object. You can use the specification within the domain object or not. I don't put any login inside my domain objects, I prefer to create services to and put all the logic there.

Comment: @Rui Jarimba I can and have used specifications within the service layer just as you suggest but I do find with that approach is that you end up with all your logic sitting in services and an anemic Domain model.  Same approach with services, I want to avoid the Service locator anti pattern so I inject into the domain object interested in using it.  Alternative is double dispatching etc.  Do you not think there is benefit in this approach to provide domain objects/entites with meaningful behaviour rather than being DTOs in effect? so entity.dosomething() versus service.dosomething(entity)

Comment: @jonathandudgeon: No need to use Service locator. I think I wasn't clear enough, sorry if I caused any confusion. When I said **services** I meant **Domain Services**, I wasn't referring to the **Services layer**. See the section **Services** in the following article to understand what I mean: http://www.developerfusion.com/article/10077/domain-driven-design-a-step-by-step-guide-part-2/

Comment: @jonathandudgeon quoting the article: `**Shouldn’t Logic Be on the Entities Directly?** Yes, it really should. We should be modelling our Entities with the logic that relates to them and their children. But **sometimes that logic either doesn’t fit on the Entity, or it would make the Entity bloated and unwieldy**. That is when Services come into the picture. They help us split logic that deals with multiple Entities, or that deals with complex operations or external responsibilities, into a separate structure more suited to the task`

Comment: @Rui Jarimba I understand. My question seems to reflect some discussion in the DDD Domain about anemic models  E.g for any given entity I would almost immediately split out business rules from my domain object and then inject in for consumption. I would use IOC to push all construction concerns together.  This resolves anemic Domain objects, but in saying that I am reading up on some debate in this area - and I think my concern re Anemic Models comes from my experience of SOA architecture (layer apon layer of DTO's and mapping)

Comment: @jonathandudgeon There are many DDD topics with completely different opinions, this topic (where to put the business logic) is just one of them :)

Answer (score 2):

Re this question, after some investigation following Rui's helpful comments I have concluded that my intention to inject services into an entity is flawed.  The answer to my original question therefore is to use Domain Events instead which reduces coupling considerably, or alternatively using 'double dispatch' as per link below.  I am currently looking at nServiceBus as the tech for implementing Domain Events (and as an introduction into nServiceBus itself)

The following article helped clear my mind on types of services and how to use with a Domain model:

[Domain Events Salvation](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/06/14/domain-events-salvation/)